# C++ Eigen Matrix Operations vs. Memory Allocation Performance

Tags: c++, performance, memory-management, matrix, eigen

I have an algorithm that requires the construction of an NxN matrix inside a function that will return the product of this matrix with an Nx1 vector that's also built on the fly.
(N is usually 8 or 9, but must be generalized for values greater than that).

I'm using the Eigen library for performing algebraic operations that are even more complex (least squares and several other constrained problems), so switching it isn't an option.

I've *benchmarked* the functions, and there's a huge bottleneck due to the intensive memory
allocations. I aim to build a thread safe application, so, for some cases, I replaced these matrices and vectors with references to elements from a global vector that serves as a provider for objects that cannot be stored on the stack. This avoids calling the constructors/destructors of the Eigen matrices and vectors, but it's not an elegant solution and it can lead to huge problems if considerable care is not taken.

As such, does Eigen either offer a workaround because I don't see the option of passing an allocator as a template argument for these objects, OR is there a more obvious thing to do?

Comment: Does `N` change between the calls? If yes, then how did you prepare this "global object" when you do not know what `N` will be?

Comment: N does not change between calls. It is dependent on the input data model the object being processed is created from.

Comment: Then maybe you can make your "resource manager" a `static` within your function. Otherwise the global one is hard to avoid IMO. It should not be very hard I think. You should get away with something simple, i.e. with out garbage collection, or any clean ups.

Comment: Due to the multithreaded constraints, it should be better to have an external/global provider for these matrices, on a thread-wise basis.

Comment: You can have locks within the resource manager. It shouldn't matter if it's `static` or not. Of course if your app spams allocations it will get serialized on those calls. But it do not think it's a real problem in a normal use-case. Also I don't think `eigen` exposes it's memory allocations. They do some magic to get memory alignment in order to use SSE. So best bet is to wrap the `eigen` objects themselves in some kind of resource manager like you did.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manage your own memory in a way that fits your needs and use `Eigen::Map` instead of `Eigen::Matrix` to perform calculations with it. Just make sure the data is aligned properly or notify Eigen if it isn't.

See the reference [Eigen::Map](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html) for details.

Here is short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Core>


int main() {
    int mydata[3 * 4]; // Manage your own memory as you see fit
    int* data_ptr = mydata;

    Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXi, Eigen::Unaligned> mymatrix(data_ptr, 3, 4);

    // use mymatrix like you would any another matrix
    mymatrix = Eigen::MatrixXi::Zero(3, 4);
    std::cout << mymatrix << '\n';

    // This line will trigger a failed assertion in debug mode
    // To change it see
    // http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicAssertions.html
    mymatrix = Eigen::MatrixXi::Ones(3, 6);


    std::cout << mymatrix << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To gather my comments into a full idea. Here is how I would try to do it.

Because the memory allocation in eigen is a pretty advanced stuff IMO and they do not expose much places to tap into it. The best bet is to wrap eigen objects itself into some kind of resource manager, like OP did.

I would make it a simple bin, that hold `Matrix< Scalar, Dynamic, Dynamic>` objects. This way you template the `Scalar` type and have a manager for generalized size matrices.

Whenever you call for an object, you check if you have a free object of the desired size, you return reference to it. If not, you allocate a new one. Simple. when you want to release the object, then you mark it free in the resource manager. I don't think anything more complicated is needed, but of course it's possible to implement some more sophisticated logic.

To ensure thread safety I would put a lock in the manager. Initialize it in the constructor if needed. Of course locking on `free` and `allocate` would be needed.

However depending on the work schedule. If the threads work on their own arrays I would consider to make one resource manager instance for each thread, so they don't clock each other. The thing is, that a global lock or a global manager would possibly get exhausted if you have like 12 cores working heavy on allocations/deallocations, and effectively serialize your app thourgh this one lock.

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing your default memory allocator with `jemalloc` or `tcmalloc`.  It's pretty easy to try out thanks to the `LD_PRELOAD` mechanism.

- https://github.com/jemalloc/jemalloc/wiki/Getting-Started
- http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html
- [C++ memory allocation mechanism performance comparison (tcmalloc vs. jemalloc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852731/c-memory-allocation-mechanism-performance-comparison-tcmalloc-vs-jemalloc)
- [what're the differences between tcmalloc/jemalloc and memory pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866145/whatre-the-differences-between-tcmalloc-jemalloc-and-memory-pool)

I think it works for most C++ projects as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could allocate memory for some common matrix sizes *before* calling that function with `operator new` or `operator new[]`, store the `void*` pointers somewhere and let the function itself retrieve an memory block with the right size. After that, you can use placement new for matrix construction. Details are given in *More effective C++*, item 8.

Comment: It might not be that easy, if applicable at all. Because `eigen` uses its internal allocators to take care of memory alignment. I also don't think there is a function to retrieve the amount of memory occupied by an eigen `object`.